# Improper integral convergence (values of p) $\int_{_{1}}^{\infty} \frac{\text{d}x}{\ln^p(x)}$

Tags: improper-integrals

I'm quite lost on the following problem:

For $p \ge 0$, for what values of $p$ does the integral converge (the answer given is for any value of $p$).

$$\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\text{d}x}{\ln^p(x)} $$

I can't figure out how to work out the given answer. My thought is to split this up into two integrals to consider the bounds, but then I get lost as to what comparisons I might make.

If there are multiple ways to approach this, I would appreciate seeing them, as I'm struggling with these types of problems.

Comment: Are you sure about that answer? I think comparison test shows that this integral diverges for $p \leq 1$.

Comment: Sorry, misread answer--which was part of my confusion. It diverges, yes.

Answer (score 3):

Since *(using for example the L'Hôpital's rule)*
$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac t{\ln^pt}=+\infty$$
then for $t$ sufficiently large (say for $t\ge t_0$) we have
$$\frac{1}{\ln^p t}\ge \frac1t,\quad \forall t\ge t_0$$
hence the given integral is divergent.

Answer (score 2):

Under the substitution $x=e^y$ the integral becomes
$$
\int_0^\infty e^y\cdot y^{-p}\,dy,
$$
which does not converge because the integrand diverges to infinity.

Answer (score 1):

First take $p>0$.  For large $x$ we have
$$0<\ln x<x^{1/p}$$
and so
$$\frac{1}{(\ln x)^p}>\frac{1}{x}\ .$$
Therefore
$$\int_e^\infty \frac{dx}{(\ln x)^p}$$
diverges for all $p>0$, and so the bit near $x=1$ doesn't matter.  If $p=0$ then the integrand is constant and so the integral diverges.